# node.js: Trouble using a systemcall to write a file to the /tmp directory

Tags: node.js

As an exercise, I'm trying to use a systemcall from node.js to write a small text file to the /tmp directory.  Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/node
var child_process = require("child_process");
var send = "Hello, world!";
child_process.exec('cat - > /tmp/test1', { input: send });
```

The file actually gets created; but, no content is placed in it.  Things just hang.  Can someone please tell me what I'm missing?

Also, I'd really like to know how to do this synchronously.

Thanks for any input.

```
 ... doug
```

Comment: what is `input` supposed to do? I don't see that anywhere in the documentation of `exec`. I think you'll need to use `spawn` for this.

Comment: Hmmm. I hadn't noticed that. It seems that all of the synchronous processes have the input option while none of the asynchronous processes have it.  "input" is a string value to be passed to stdin.  As mentioned, I would like to switch to synchronous anyway. I think part of my problem is that I get confused by why when we require a library we assign it to a variable.  I'm not used to that.  It seems that the name of the variable is also important.  Could you please shed some light on that.  I think that might help.

Comment: Maybe it would be better if I just cut to the chase.  How would I change my code so as to use child_process.execSync rather than child_process.exec?    I would think that that would be easily done by just changing "child_process.exec" to "child_process.execSync"  in the second line of code.  However, that doesn't seem to work.  I get complaints about there being no exec.Sync method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hm unless i forgot to rtm too, this code will just never work. There is no such input option for cp.exec.

But there is a stdio option, will let us open the expected stdio on the child.

```
child_process.exec('cat - > /tmp/test1', { stdio: 'pipe' });
```

see https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_options_stdio

`stdio`s are not string, they are streams, which we can end / write / pipe / close / push etc

see https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html

Note that stdin is a writable, stdout / stderr are readable.

To write the stdin of `cat` you ll now consume the cp.stdin object and call for its end() method.

```
child_process.exec('cat - > /tmp/test1', { stdio: 'pipe' }).stdin.end('hello world');
```

Note that end method is a write followed by a termination of the stream, which is required to tell cat to quit.

To ensure this is working well, we should refactor it, to not send stdin to a file, instead pipe child.stdout to the process.stdout.

```
var child_process = require('child_process');
var cp = child_process.exec('cat -', { stdio: 'pipe' });
cp.stdin.end('hello world');
cp.stdout.pipe(process.stderr);
```

Note that process is a global.

Comment: Awesome solution.  Thanks.  I finally got what I was originally struggling with to work.  I will offer it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got my original approach to work.  The big stumbling block is to know that the synchronous methods are only available in version 0.12 (and later) of node.js.  Here is the code that I finally got to work:

```
#!/usr/local/n/versions/node/0.12.14/bin/node

var child_process = require('child_process');
var send = "Hello, world!"
child_process.execSync('cat - > /tmp/test1', { input : send }).toString();
```

Thanks to all for the help.

```
... doug
```